# Export library as Biblatex and not Bibtex with Zotero

Tags: better-bibtex

When I mark an entry as a "Web page" in Zotero, it is automatically exported as "@misc" in my .bib file, which is causing me problems to correctly show urls in my latex document.

I have read that if Webpages are exported as "@misc" and not "@online", it is because Zotero is exporting as Bibtex and not Biblatex, but I can’t find how to change this setting (I am using the Better Bibtex addon for Zotero).

How can I change that and get my webpages to be exported as "@online"?

Comment: I don't really use Zotero, but a quick test, using the export `Better BibLaTeX` (not `Better BibTeX` seems to automatically turn web page items into `online`.

Comment: @AlanMunn how do I change from Better BibTex to Better BibLatex? I can’t find this setting anywhere.

Comment: I just installed the  Better BibTeX for Zotero plugin, and then when I choose Export, it shows up in the list of possible export formats.  You need to click on the Format drop down menu to choose it when you get the Export options dialogue.

Comment: @AlanMunn are you talking about Edit -> Preferences -> Export and set the "Item format" dropdown to "Better BiblaTex" ? But this is for Quick Copy only I think, not for the automatically exported database as a .bib file.

Comment: I was talking about the File -> Export Library menu item, not the Quick Copy preference.

Comment: @AlanMunn ha ok I wasn’t aware of this export menu, I was looking at the Preferences menu. It looks like I can now export correctly in Biblatex, although I’m still not able to see my urls printed in the references, but that is a different problem.